# C minimum/maximum function

Tags: c, c99

Is there a **standard function** in C99 to get **minimum/maximum** element in a given array using a given compare function. **Similar to that:**

```
void* get_min(void* start,size_t size,size_t elementSize,int (*compare)(const void *, const void*))
```

Comment: No.............

Comment: Why would you need it? This is trivial to write.

Comment: @DeiDei perhaps not trivial to write optimally!  There are standard functions for *sort* and *binary search* so it seems like a reasonable question

Comment: This is kinda the difference between Python and C philosophy. I understand where OP is coming from. Using a well-optimized and debugged library function or a home-crafted buggy sub-optimal algorithm? :)

Comment: You can sort the array using the comparison function, then get the first and last elements of the result.

Comment: @Barmar You could, but a linear search would be faster.

Comment: The answer is indeed "no". What *you* could do is write one as an answer, then self-accept it and get lots of reputation :D

Comment: @Barmar,this is not very good because the complexity of sort is bounded by Omega(nlog(n)) where as you can very simply get minimum in O(n)

Comment: @DanielMeltzer dbush already said that. But [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @M.M The performance of the built-in quick sort function is [far from optimal](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/rants/c++-vs-c/) since everything is passed by way of pointers and barely any inlining is possible. If computational efficiency is of any concern to you, you'll actually want to give the libc builtin a wide berth.
(I want to make clear though that I agree with your main point that the question makes total sense. Just wanted to point out this little detail).

Comment: @undercat yeah that is the point I am making, the standard library doesn't have a bunch of algorithms  because it's nigh impossible to make versions that are both standard and optimal

Comment: @DeiDei: `strlen()` and `strcpy()` are even more trivial, yet they exist in the standard library.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'd hardly call the highly optimized implementation by most standard library vendors to be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there is not such standard function, so here is my solution:

#### For minimum:

```
 void* get_min(void* start,size_t size,size_t elementSize,int (*compare)(const void *, const void*))
    {
        char* minObject = start;
        for(int i = elementSize;i<size*elementSize;i+=elementSize){
            char* object = start+i;
            if(compare(object,minObject)<0){
                minObject = object;
            }
        }
        return minObject;
    }
```

#### and for maximum:

```
void* get_max(void* start,size_t size,size_t elementSize,int (*compare)(const void *, const void*))
{
    char* maxObject = start;
    for(int i = elementSize;i<elementSize*size;i+=elementSize){
        char* object = start+i;
        if(compare(object,maxObject)>0){
            maxObject = object;
        }
    }
    return maxObject;
}
```

Comment: A copy/paste error in `get_max()`: change `compare(object,minObject)>0` to `compare(object,maxObject)>0`

Comment: I believe that there is also a logic error in the `i<size` test of the `for` loops.

Comment: You're using i as byte offset instead of subscript, so it should start at elementSize not 1.